# Hudson autobuild + ANT Ftp settings

Tags: ant, ftp, hudson

i've configured the hudson with ant to compile the project, which is working fine.

After the compile i want the script to upload the output directory to the remote ftp server.

This is the ant script i'm using:

```
<target name="deploy">
    <ftp server="${ftp.url}"
        port="${ftp.port}"
        remotedir="${ftp.dir}"
        userid="${ftp.user}"
        verbose="yes"
        password="${ftp.pass}">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}${output.dir}">
          <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
</target>
```

It is working!

Before each compile, the hudson reverts all of the changed files. ( basicaly there are 2, the version file, and the compiled file ).

I want the script to upload only the newer files to the server. But when i'm adding to `ftp` node an attribute: `depends="yes"` or `newer="yes"`, i'm getting and error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/oro/text/regex/MalformedPatternException`

Ant is using these jar files:

### - ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar

### - commons-net-1.4.1.jar

Any suggestions? If need more information ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add jakarta-oro to the classpath, this information is buried a bit in [the installing apache ant guid](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#commons-net)

> jakarta-oro 2.0.8 or later is required together with commons-net
>   1.4.0. For all users, a minimum version of commons-net of 1.4.0 is recommended. Earlier versions did not support the full range of
>   configuration options, and 1.4.0 is needed to compile Ant.